# Javascript: Cannot modify an array declared outside a loop from inside the loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
var myArray = "AAAAA";
    for(var i = 0; i < ["a", "b"].length; i++)
    {
        alert(myArray);
        var myVar = "C"+myArray[1]+"C";
        myArray[1] = "K";
        //myArray.splice(3,1);
    }
```

With the splice commented out, it just alerts AAAAA both times.

With the splice, it alerts AAAAA the first time, then doesn't alert again. (Javascript stopped working after it hit the splice)

I have no idea what's wrong.
Obviously the array is accessible from within the loop, but why can't it be modified?

Any help is welcome, thanks guys and girls!

Comment: `myArray` isn't an array it's a string. Open your console and look at your errors. They will give you insight on how to start fixing your code. Read a tutorial or two on javascript strings and arrays (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: That's not an array (even if you call it one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myArray` is not an `Array`, therefore an `Uncaught TypeError` is thrown.

Assuming that you intended `myArray` to be `['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']`, you can use the `split()` method:

```
//var myArray = 'AAAAA'; // This is not an Array did you mean:
var myArray = 'AAAAA'.split('');

//var myVar; // Should declare this here

// What is the purpose of i < ['a', 'b'].length? why not i < 2?
for(var i = 0; i < ['a', 'b'].length; i++) {
    alert(myArray.join()); // Turn Array back into a string

    /** 
     *  This has function scope, not block scope (declare above)
     *  (I'm guessing you use this value later?)
     */
    var myVar = 'C' + myArray[1] + 'C';

    myArray[1] = 'K';
    myArray.splice(3,1);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 2):

Try: `var myArray = ["AAAAA"];`
This declares `myArray` as an array rather than a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle your string as a character array:

```
var myArray = "AAAAA".split('')
```

Answer (score 1):

As jdawg says myArray is not an array is a string. The code stops because throws an Error when it attempts to call a function (splice) does not exists in String.

You can modify an array in a loop.

Other way to transorm a string in an array is

```
 var myArray = myString.split ('')
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that `myArray` is not an array, try

```
var myArray = ["AAAAA"];
    for(var i = 0; i < ["a", "b"].length; i++)
    {
        alert(myArray);
        var myVar = "C"+myArray[1]+"C";
        myArray[1] = "K";
        myArray.splice(3,1);
    }
```